# Filter array by object property, then add together another property's values between the filtered objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array of objects:

```
let alertItems = 
    [
      {
        name: 'Dan Test Q',
        warning: 0,
        severe: 0,
        critical: 1,
        w: false,
        s: false,
        c: true,
        thresholds: { warning: 1, severe: 2, critical: 3 }
      },
      {
        name: 'Dan Test Q 2',
        warning: 0,
        severe: 1,
        critical: 0,
        w: false,
        s: false,
        c: true,
        thresholds: { warning: 1, severe: 2, critical: 3 }
      },
      {
        name: 'Dan Test Q 2',
        warning: 1,
        severe: 1,
        critical: 0,
        w: false,
        s: false,
        c: true,
        thresholds: { warning: 1, severe: 2, critical: 3 }
      }
    ]
```

I am trying to add the warning, severe, and critical items together for each `name`.

Basically for Dan Test Q the output should show that warning = 0, severe = 1 and critical = 0.

For Dan Test Q 2 the output should show that warning = 1, severe = 2, critical = 0

I believe I need to use filter for this, but I'm starting to confuse myself.

```
        let queues = {queues: [{queueId: "Dan Test Q"}, {queueId: "Dan Test Q 2"}]}
        let queueItems = alertItems.filter(item => {
            // I'm not sure what to do here to achieve my goal
        })

        console.log(queueItems)
```

The queues variable contains the list of queues. I thought perhaps using a for loop and looping over the queues would help, but doing that just confused me even more.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: For Dan Test Q the output should show that warning = 0, severe = 1 and critical = 0. For Dan Test Q 2 the output should show that warning = 1, severe = 2, critical = 0.

Comment: Understood but what structure are you looking for?

Comment: For now, my goal was just to get the data added together per queue, so I wasn't to concerned about what structure is involved. Looking at the answers, I have a better idea of what I want to do with the returned data now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) to iterate over the queues, adding the `warning`, `severe` and `critical` properties to another object:

```js
let queueItems = 
    [
      {
        name: 'Dan Test Q',
        warning: 0,
        severe: 0,
        critical: 1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Dan Test Q 2',
        warning: 0,
        severe: 1,
        critical: 0,
      },
      {
        name: 'Dan Test Q 2',
        warning: 1,
        severe: 1,
        critical: 0,
      }
    ]


const result = {}

queueItems.forEach((q) => {
  // If this key doesn't exist in the result, we add it and add default values
  if (!result.hasOwnProperty(q.name)) {
    result[q.name] = { warning: 0, severe: 0, critical: 0 }
  }
  
  // Add on the attributes from this queue
  result[q.name].warning += q.warning
  result[q.name].severe += q.severe
  result[q.name].critical += q.critical
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I was wondering if map was the way to go... This is perfect. Thanks so much!

Comment: This is an improper use of `map()`. There are other methods to just loop an array

Comment: @charlietfl is correct. A `forEach` would be better here. Updated the answer

Comment: @charlietfl Why is this improper?

Comment: A `map` iterates over the array, but it creates a new array with the returned result inside the map. Since we don't need to return anything here, nor do we need to do anything with the new array from a map, it's a bit pointless. We just want to iterate over the array, so a `forEach` is better here.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically wanting a *"groupBy"* operation where you use the common vales as keys in an object

```js
let group = {};

queueItems.forEach(({name, ...rest})=>{
    group[name] = group[name] || {name, warning: 0, severe: 0, critical: 0};
    ['warning', 'severe', 'critical'].forEach(k => group[name][k] += rest[k]);
});

const res = Object.values(group)
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
let queueItems=[{name:"Dan Test Q",warning:0,severe:0,critical:1,w:!1,s:!1,c:!0,thresholds:{warning:1,severe:2,critical:3}},{name:"Dan Test Q 2",warning:0,severe:1,critical:0,w:!1,s:!1,c:!0,thresholds:{warning:1,severe:2,critical:3}},{name:"Dan Test Q 2",warning:1,severe:1,critical:0,w:!1,s:!1,c:!0,thresholds:{warning:1,severe:2,critical:3}}];
</script>
```